# Get user input to php file

Tags: php

I am very new to php just starting learning from internet. I seen some examples for file handling. But when I'm following the same procedure to **file writing** it's not working.

The Reading function is working file. But writing to a file isn't working. I have also tried to use **file_put_content** function to write. :(

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    $fileName = "Text.txt";
    $fh = fopen($fileName,"a") or die("can not open the file to write");

    //Writing to a file
    $newData = "Hello This is new Data";
    fwrite($fh,$newData);
    fclose($fh);

    //Reading a file -- Working
    $text = fopen("Text.txt","r") or die ("can not open the file to read");     
    while(!feof($text))
    {
        $myLine = fgets($text);
        print $myLine;
    }
    fclose($text);
    }

?>
```

Please Guide me..
Thanks

Comment: It's not working because it shows "can not open the file to write" ?

Comment: You should check your folder/file permissions - does the account have access to that file to write? Post the error message you are getting to help pin down the problem.

Comment: Yes this message is appearing in file writing section. but in file reading case it is working fine.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? It is probably a rights matter, try to give the folder you are working in extra rights (look into `chmod`). But be careful, don't go around and give everything all rights to everything. This will create a big security risk!

Comment: @ Fluffeh -- I'm not getting any error.

Comment: what errors are you getting, what user is running the script? Does the user have write access? BTW: it's `file_put_contents`, with an `s` at the end. Also [read this](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die) since you're new, there's no point in learning bad practices

Comment: @ManishKumarNamdev: If you're getting the `can not open the file to write` message, you're getting an error (the `die` bit is only executed when the statement it precedes failed)... anyway looks like a permissions issue to me: `chmod` and `chown` is what will resolve your issue

Comment: Thanks Fluffeh I found there was a folder/file permission issue. Now it is working

Answer (score 1):

This works fine, what is the error you get ?

```
  <?php
    $file = 'text.txt';
    $writer = fopen($file, 'a');
    $addData = 'This is a new string to be added at the end of the file';
    fwrite($writer, $addData);
    fclose($writer);
  ?>
```

EDIT1:
To Enter the input from POST request you can do something like this:

```
    <?php
      if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $addData = $_POST['input-name'];
        $file = 'text.txt';
        $writer = fopen($file, 'a');

        fwrite($writer, $addData);
        fclose($writer);
      }
    ?>
```